# Downgrade xorg-server

Tags: 14.04, xorg, downgrade

According to this [bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89172#c0), intel-virtual-output encounter some difficulties with xorg-server version 1.17.1:

```
david@david-ubuntu:~$ intel-virtual-output 
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 20 requests (20 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

As reported by a user, downgrading to version 1.16 would solve the problem. How can I safely downgrade the xorg package?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: sorry, i'm using ubuntu gnome 14.04.3

Comment: Is it 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: It is  a 64 bit version

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can downgrade your `xserver-xorg` to 1.16 in Ubuntu 14.04 by running

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

You can check the version by `dpkg -l | grep "ii  xserver-xorg-core"`

Comment: That installed xorg v1.16, but at the next rebbot lead the computer to a black screen before login, maybe due to my previously done configuration for bumblebee...

Comment: You will need to re-install all the nvidia stuff. I can't help with bumblebee.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm trying, perhaps it is convenient to reinstall completely ubuntu and firstly downgrade. Have I to block somehow the xorg version to prevent an upgrade? I think I can mark as solved the answer after that. Thanks

Comment: You do not need to block anything. The xorg major versions do not change on regular upgrades. They are in different packages. 3.16 is `lts-utopic`, 3.17 is `lts-vivid`.