# Messed up updates. Managed to get to desktop, but can't install Fglrx drivers back

Tags: drivers, xorg, fglrx

Ok so, I did a Hardware Security Update in Ubuntu 14.04, but noticed my fglrx drivers getting removed, then I closed the update manager which lead to me not being able to enter into the graphical interface, I managed to fix that, but now I have X Org drivers and want to install fglrx drivers back. But I get this error:

```
0 ✓ xxmonster@xxmonster-desktop ~ $ sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx-updates : Depends: 

                          xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                          xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                          xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                          xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                          xorg-video-abi-15 or
                          xorg-video-abi-18 or
                          xorg-video-abi-19
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Should I try doing sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates xorg-video-abi-11 xorg-video-abi-12 xorg-video-abi-13 ... x-org-video-abi-18 xorg-video-abi-19. I don't know what to do and I need help.

Comment: Are you sure that update wasn't an upgrade to 16.04?

Comment: I don't know, it was a Ubuntu Hardware Security Update (Ubuntu 14.04 HWE), it could have been, but hopefully it wasn't, because I want to use the fglrx driver, I am still in 14.04.5 though.

Comment: I've found something. I'm going to put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the information page about the LTSEnablement Stack on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), updates bring along new kernels and new versions of Xorg.

The problem here is the new version of Xorg. 16.04 doesn't work with `fglrx` because it shipped with Xorg 1.18, which isn't compatible. 14.04 usually works fine because it came with 1.16.

With that Hardware Security Update, you installed a newer kernel, but you also installed a newer version of Xorg: one that is incompatible with `fglrx`. I honestly don't think there's a way to downgrade that safely, and since you cancelled the upgrade halfway through, your system is already unstable.

Of course, it's possible to recover everything and downgrade without breaking anything, but it is going to take a lot of effort. If you really need `fglrx`, I suggest you either reinstall 14.04 and don't take HWE upgrades, or check here for some options if you're going to stay where you are: [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-and-amd-graphics)

**Update:** it appears you can downgrade Xorg back to 1.16. I am not able to test the safety of this, nor whether or not it functions, so try it at your own risk. [Downgrade xorg-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676216/downgrade-xorg-server)

Comment: I might try to reinstall it, I can copy the important stuff from my ubuntu partition somewhere else.

Comment: I guess it was a bad decision to install the HWE upgrades.

Comment: But if I reinstall, would it automatically install the HWE stuff?

Comment: You can downgrade Xorg it seems http://askubuntu.com/questions/676216/downgrade-xorg-server

Comment: wait, so I can fix my fglrx driver?

Comment: If the downgrade succeeds. __Back up your data.__

Comment: Ok I'll backup my data and then downgrade. I'll tell you if it worked.

Comment: it seems that it downgraded, now I'll try installing the drivers. It's installing them.

Comment: So it downgraded ok, I can say that it was a safe downgrade and I managed to reinstall the drivers and everything works fine. The thing is I couldn't see what package updates will the HWE do, even though at other updates I could see that.

Comment: The Wiki I linked might have some info. I saw it upgraded the kernel and X, which was all I needed to know, but maybe it does other things too.

Comment: yeah I noticed it tried to upgrade the kernel and Xorg, but when it did that, it had to remove my fglrx driver, that's when I cancelled the update. Also the downgrade of Xorg server seems to download a kernel version 3.16, but it didn't remove my current one 4.2.0 and it only added it in Advanced Options thing in Grub. So I am still in 4.2.0 after downgrade.

Comment: The default kernel in 14.04 IIRC was 3.16, so it makes sense that it installed it. You can have multiple kernel versions without any issue.