# Unable to switch to proprietary fglrx video driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx, amd-graphics

Everything was working fine until today I decided to allow Ubuntu to upgrade some software - including chrome and some parts of Ubuntu. After restarting I was noticing some screen tearing while watching Netflix so I tried installing something to fix it called Bumblebee - but I ended up uninstalling it because I don't think it applies for AMD drivers. I then did a apt-get autoremove since the console suggested it and a whole bunch of stuff got removed that I'm not sure should have been. Eventually I went back into "Additional Drivers" and saw that somehow my video card driver had gotten switched back to the open source driver instead of fglrx which is what it was previously set to when everything was working fine. I can click the button to select fglrx and hit apply changes but the selection goes back to the open source driver after a few seconds. I tried installing via commandline following these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD but I ran into another error that comes up when I run

`sudo apt-get install fglrx`

It says something like this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23...libcheese7... but it is not going to be installed.
```

I tried installing those separately but it didn't seem to work.

Anyone out there that can help?

I never seem to learn my lesson - I violated a personal commandment of software that I have - never upgrade anything unless you have an urgent reason to.

Here is my current system settings:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Memory: 3.3 GiB
Processor: AMD Athlon 5350 APU with Radeon R3x4
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD KABINI (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
OS type: 64 bit

Comment: not a duplicate at all, I am unable to get back to fglrx even though I was using it just fine before some software upgrades (none of which were major). That post just talks about options for graphics cards on 16.04. I just want to go back to fglrx but I can't due to some weird bug apparently.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the packages you removed, or the dependencies listed?

Comment: @Barodapride you upgraded Ubuntu components; you upgraded to 14.04.5. As the title indicates, the question applies to 14.04.5.

Comment: I ran the command line answer from here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/676216/downgrade-xorg-server

It seemed to let me change to fglrx but then I got some error saying it could not be applied. When I restarted my computer now comes up with a weird error message about the graphics and some options to fix it but none of them seem to do anything. I can't even get a console. But the good news is I submitted a report and it is a known bug - great!

Comment: @Zacharee1 how can I tell my computer to roll back that 14.04.5 update so I can switch back to fglrx?

Comment: @Barodapride you can't. What you can do is read the answer and see that there is a workaround

Comment: I see that I can downgrade Xorg (whatever that is) on 14.04, but I guess I don't have 14.04 anymore I have 14.04.5? Still, I tried that process last night and while it did let me select fglrx, the screen comes up black on reboot. I guess I'll have to reinstall 14.04(.0?) fresh again - not a huge deal since I don't really have anything important on the machine.